# 5 black, 7 red, 9 blue, and 6 white marbles.

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I'm having trouble finding how many ways there is to arrange 5 black, 7 red, 9 blue, and 6 white marbles to find the probability that every white marble is adjacent to at least one other white marble.

If you could help me out that would be great!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are, in general, $n!$ ways to arrange $n$ objects. So you'd have $(5+7+9+6)!$ but then as all the black marbles are identical, their permutations shouldn't be counted. For every 'good' permutation, you also have another $5!7!9!6!$ that only differ from it by permutations of same colored marbles. Thus the result is $\frac{(5+7+9+6)!}{5!7!9!6!}$.

For the probability, consider that whites must be in pairs or triples. This is equivalent to solving the previous problem for $3$ and $2$ white marbles. Notice that the two cases overlap when all $6$ marbles are in one group.

Answer (score 2):

First find the total probability space of the marbles. I assume the marbles of each color are otherwise indistinguishable and so order doesn't matter.

$N_{all} = \frac{(5+7+9+6)!}{5!\cdot7!\cdot9!\cdot6!}$

Second, create an expression for the number of combinations of the black, red, and blue marbles, this will be the number of contexts for the white marbles .

$N_{contexts} = \frac{(5+7+9)!}{5!\cdot7!\cdot9!}$

Our total probability is going to equal...

$P = \frac{N_{contexts} \cdot N_{whites}}{N_{all}} = \frac{21!6!}{27!} \cdot N_{whites}$

Next think about how many ways every white marble can be adjacent to at least one other white marble: (2,2,2), (2,4), (3,3), and (6,0)

The (6,0) case is the easiest because there is only one moveable entity. There are (5+7+9)+1 possible locations within the other marbles (5+7+9 locations before another marble and an extra 1 location at the very end).

$N_{1} = 22$

The (3,3) case and the (4,2) case have equal combinations because they both have two moveable entities. The first set of white marbles can be in (5+7+9)+1 possible locations, and that leaves (5+7+9) locations for the second set. Order shouldn't matter, so we get...

$N_{2} = \frac{(5+7+9+1)(5+7+9)}{2} = 231$

For the (2,2,2) case (our last one!), we have (5+7+9)+1 locations for our first pair, (5+7+9) for our second, and (5+7+9)-1 for our third. Again order shouldn't matter, so we get...

$N_{3} = \frac{22!}{19!\cdot3!} = 1540$

Now, we say that $N_{whites} = N_1 + 2 \cdot N_2 + N_3 = 2024$ and plug that value into the original formula and we get...

$P = \frac{21!6!}{27!} \cdot 2024 = .00683...$

So the final probability is about 0.7%.

Comment: Just realized that for calculation of $N_2$, order doesn't matter for the (3,3) sets but does matter for the (2,4) sets, i.e. they should be distinct from (4,2) arrangements. Therefore the formula for $N_{whites}$ should be $N_{whites} = N_1 + 3 \cdot N_2 + N_3 = 2255$. The final probability would then be about .00761 (0.761%).

Comment: Should give hints to homework, not a complete solution.

Comment: @MichaelChernick That was my first answer on stack exchange. I'll know better next time!

Comment: I was just trying to inform nit to reprimand.  Thank you for adding the tag.

Answer (score 1):

We describe one way to count the number of ways to arrange the balls.

Let the number of ways to place the white marbles be $W$. Each of these ways  leaves $21$ empty slots. Let $N$ be the number of ways to fill these slots. Then our answer is $WN$.

Finding $N$ is probably a standard problem for you.

Finding $W$ is more complicated. We can split into cases. First count the number of ways to place the white marbles so they are all together.

Then count the $4$-$2$ splits (and the $2$-$4$ splits). Then count the $3$-$3$ splits, and finally the $2$-$2$-$2$ splits.

The counting of, for example, the $4$-$2$ splits is not hard. Imagine the non-whites lined up. Then there are $22$ gaps between them, including the end "gaps." Choose $2$ of these.

For the probability, divide by the number of ways to place the balls with no restriction.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way is to compute the complement.

The 21 "non-white" marbles have 22 "interstices" (including ends), so the white marbles can be placed in C(22,6) "non-adjacent" ways and the others permuted in 21!/(5!7!9!) ways in their positions

Pr = 1 - [C(22,6)*21!/(5!7!9!)]/[27!/(5!7!9!6!)]

= 1 - C(22,6)*6!21!/27!