# How many ways can we put $5$ red balls, $4$ green balls and $3$ white balls into $12$ slots?

Tags: permutations

How many ways can we put $5$ red balls, $4$ green balls and $3$ white balls into $12$ slots?

Would it be $12!$ or $\dfrac{12!}{5!4!3!}$? I'm confused here.

Comment: There no condition, so it is 12!.

Comment: It could depend on whether for example swapping the order of two red balls would count as a different arrangement or not.

Comment: @Henry I see, but nothing like that is mentioned in the question. So I'm guessing the question is more or less .. how many ways to put 12 balls in 12 slots?

Comment: I think it's more likely that the red balls are to be considered indistinguishable, likewise the green, likewise the white.

Comment: I'm going with 12! as the answer then..

Comment: @Henry they wouldn't bother with the colors if red balls were distinguihsable from each other.

Comment: @Soke: You may be correct, if you assume that questions only ever give useful information.

Comment: see $N_{all}$ in [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/203575/149016) answer. According to it it should be 12!/5!4!3!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since (red/green/white) balls are indistinguishable from other (red/green/white) balls, the answer is $\dfrac{12!}{5!4!3!}$, not $12!$.